# How can I add ~/.local/bin to my PATH?

Tags: paths, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm just trying to follow [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref) tutorial and set up my environment. My system is WSL Ubuntu 18.04. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix/14638025#14638025) is already an answer on my question, but I as an absolute novice in Linux/UNIX don't know which variant presented there more suitable for my goal.
Do I need to add this string

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dir"
```

into my ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file?

Or may I need to accomplish the second step from the answer?

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /path/to/binary binary-name
```

And then run these commands?

```
source ~/.profile 
or
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Add it to your `.bashrc`

Comment: The `.bashrc` file should be fine!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you make a `~/bin` folder in your home folder, it'll already be in your default path. No need to modify anything, or add folders to a hidden .local folder. Create the `~/bin` folder, log out, log back in, and open a `terminal` window, and you can confirm the path by typing `echo $PATH`.

**Update #1:**

If you decide to use `~/.local/bin` anyway, add this to the end of your ~/.profile...

```sh
# set PATH so it includes user's private ~/.local/bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then log out, log back in, and your new path will be available.

Comment: According the tutorial (link in my question) next command
python -m site --user-base
should output ~/.local/bin
But now only ~/.local
This command - export PYTHONUSERBASE=/myappenv
solve the problem, but only till reload.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh that tutorial, and extra link, is TL;DR, but is mostly for linux and Mac. I'd follow something else as a learning guide.

Comment: What is TL;DR? I need a guide for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @AlexStelmakh  Too Long;Didn't Read. See https://help.ubuntu.com/ for help guides on Ubuntu.

Comment: ~/.local (with ~ expanded to the absolute path to your home directory) so you’ll need to add ~/.local/bin to your PATH. You can set your PATH permanently by modifying ~/.profile.
I'm trying to follow these instructions. And accordingly it is not as simple as adding /bin in my home directory.

Comment: If you're still trying to use ~/.local/bin, it'll mean that you'll (normally) use the `terminal` to see it, or set the `Files` app to show hidden files, as .local is a hidden folder, due to the leading period. If you just create a bin folder in your home, then log out/in, it'll automatically be in your path, and you can manipulate files in the bin folder using the normal `Files` app. If you're still using that tutorial, I'd recommend using another one, as it was mostly for Linux/Mac users. Otherwise edit your .profile PATH.

Comment: I'm using WSL ubuntu without GUI, so I use terminal and aware that .local is hidden. I have no idea why I can't use tutorial for Linux? It's the same as official Python doc about pipenv installation.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh  OK, then go ahead and modify your .profile or .bashrc, and expand the PATH statement to include ~/.local/bin.

Comment: Could you tell me exact command that I should add to .profile? Sorry I totally confused. Instead of learning Python, I fighting second day with this s**t.

Comment: See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: It doesn't change the PYTHONUSERBASE.  It still ~/.local. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh You could add `export PYTHONUSERBASE=/myappenv` to ~/.profile.

Comment: ~/.local/bin appears to be in PATH on ubuntu 20.04 tho, it is set in ~/.profile when it exists

Answer (score 4):

The `PATH` variable gets changed when this shell command is executed:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/your/new/path
```

The `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` will be executed automatically when you open a bash session (normally when you open a new terminal window/tab).

So if you want to change the `PATH` in current shell session only, you could just type `export PATH=xxx` and execute it once. But if you want to make it difference permanently, you should add the command above into `~/.bashrc` **or** `~/.profile`.

Comment: Should be the second part of the command enclosed in quotes?
Like this one.
export PATH="$PATH:/home/maverick/.local/bin"
As this (https://tinyurl.com/y86jc2pp) answer suggests it should be enclosed.
I entered the command above, but PATH still the same.
I proved this by next command:
python -m site --user-base
And the result's as follows:
/home/maverick/.local

Comment: @AlexStelmakh `python -m site --user-base` just tell you where the pip packages are installed at. You can view the `PATH` in the current bash session by the command `echo $PATH`.