# bash: mp3chaps command not found

Tags: command-line, bash

i try to run [mp3chaps](https://github.com/dskrad/mp3chaps) command like

```
mp3chaps -i episode_42.mp3
```

but terminal return me this error

```
bash: mp3chaps command not found
```

I'm pretty sure I have mp3chaps installed, I tried use also [this](https://github.com/jcs/mp3chap) too

but it gives me the same error.

```
bash: mp3chap command not found
```

What did I forget?

**Ubuntu version**: 18.04

Comment: If installed, you need the binary path included on $PATH. `locate -b mp3chap` to find the binary

Comment: @PabloBianchi binary path are these: https://i.imgur.com/KfgSDCv.png - which command should I use to add mp3chap or mp3chaps on $PATH ?

Comment: [`~/.local/bin/`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113838/349837)

Comment: @JackRock You could add the following to ~/.profile: `export PATH="$PATH:/home/appbox/.local/bin"` and perhaps then most easily reboot... There is a choice of *append* or *prepend* to the $PATH, this example is *append*.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version you are using? Please add the information to your question - use "edit"

Comment: @vanadium ok, I use Ubuntu 18.04, I add now this information in question

Answer (score 0):

Your `$PATH` statement needs to be modified so that this application can be opened easily. Using your preferred text editor open the file `~/.profile` and add the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/appbox/.local/bin"
```

With this done you can either run the command `source ~/.profile` or simply reboot your computer and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

On a standard Ubuntu desktop, a directory `~/.local/bin` is automatically added to the PATH when you log in. There is code for that in a standard `~/.profile`. If it does not for you, then that would indicate you are having a custom `~/.profile` or not running an Ubuntu desktop.

So before adding the PATH to your `.profile`, log out then back in. `~/.local/bin should then be included in your PATH.